# How to access an html sub page from address bar?

Tags: html, pdf, wiki

The following works for PDF: URL#name

The following works for Wiki: URL/#Name

HTML opens the site, not the sub page:

URL#Name

**Wiki code fragment:**

< a name="L5.1"></ a>

## 5.1 Backups

**HTML Code Fragment:**

< a name="L5.1">

< h2 class="western">5.1 Usage Options

**TeX code fragment:**
\subsection{Usage Options}

Working Wiki Link:
https://sourceforge.net/p/windows-power-utilities/wiki/Windows%20Power%20Tips/#L1.2

**NOT** Working HTML Links:

file:///D:/U/WP/Kryptmin.html?name=#L5.1

file:///D:/U/WP/Kryptmin.html#L5.1

**Working PDF Link:**

file:///D:/U/WP/Kryptmin.pdf#subsection.7.1

What is correct syntax for HTML link?

TIA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` attribute with the same value as `name`:

```
<a name="L5.1" id="L5.1"></ a>
```

`name` attribute is **[obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features:the-a-element)** in html5:

> Authors should not specify the name attribute on a elements. ...  If this attribute is present and the element has an ID, then the attribute's value must be equal to the element's ID.

---

P.S.

- By the way `name` for `a` still should work according to [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#find-a-potential-indicated-element) part of spec.
- `name` attribute [was present](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-name-A) in html4 for `a`, but [not listed](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element:concept-element-attributes) in html5.